# Change owner of all objects

Tags: permissions, powershell, groups

Is it possible to change the owner of all lists, libraries, and pages on SharePoint 2010? Our developers logged in via their personal accounts to the dev server and so SharePoint took their account as the owner. Will this pose an issue with any objects? We've noticed that with SharePoint groups, only the person who created them can delete them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex, why can't you add developer account as a Site Collection administrator to have complete access to lists, libraries and pages. You can delete, update and add new stuff as per your liking.